# Cannot Instantiate Servlet

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I'm getting HTTP Status 500 or 404 while trying to start my server

This is a ubuntu server, running through netbeans/java-EE and i'm not sure about what's wrong.

i'll paste some code to show my servlet and my web.xml

> Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>contato</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>contato</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>contato</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/contato</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

> Contato.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import db.Mensagem;
import db.MensagemDAO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Desenvolvimento
 */
public class contato extends HttpServlet {


   /**
    * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
    *
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
    * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
    */
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
         /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
         out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title>Entrar em Contato</title>");
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Área de Contato </h1>");
         out.println("</body>");

         out.println("<form action=\"contato\" method=\"GET\">");
         out.println("<pre><label>Descrição: </label> <input name=\"descricao\"></input> </pre>");
         out.println("<pre><button type=\"submit\">OK</button> </pre>");
         out.println("</form>");

         try{
            MensagemDAO dao = new MensagemDAO();
            ArrayList<Mensagem> mensagens = dao.select("select * from mensagem");

            out.println("<h3>Menesagens do sistema</h3>");

            for(Mensagem mensagem:mensagens){
               out.println("<pre>"+mensagem.getDescricao()+"</pre>");
            }

         }catch(Exception e){
            out.println("<span>ERRO: "+ e.toString() +" </span>");
         }

         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
      }
   }

   /**
    * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
    *
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
    * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
    */
   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
      String descricao = request.getParameter("descricao");

      Mensagem nova = new Mensagem();
      nova.setDescricao(descricao);

      try{
         MensagemDAO dao = new MensagemDAO();
         dao.insert(nova);
      }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e.toString());
      }

   }

}
```

If i change in web.xml the servlet to classes.contato.java i get error 500, error instantiating servlet class

else i get error 404 not found.

both errors on http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/contato

my Tomcat logs https://pastebin.com/TFL5Qkry, pastebin.com/QHrGexXL

I'll appreciate immensely any help :)

Comment: In your listing of **contato.java** there is no `package` statement, so your servlet will be in [the default package](https://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-the-default-package/126). However, in your **web.xml** file you specified `<servlet-class>classes.contato</servlet-class>`, meaning that your `contato` servlet is in package `classes`. Amend that line to `<servlet-class>contato</servlet-class>`, then restart Tomcat and try again. [This article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm) gives an example of a servlet with no package specified, which may be helpful.

Comment: Well it still didn't work 
i did
`servlet>
        <servlet-name>contato</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>contato</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>contato</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/contato</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  `

Comment: OK. Please update your question with the following information: [1] Show the current content of **web.xml**. [2] Show the content of Tomcat's server log when you access your servlet in a browser. [3] Specify the URL entered in the browser which results in the 404 error.

Comment: how do i make a log? besides that  i did 1 and 3

Comment: [1] Why are you entering "WebApplication2" as part of the URL? Is that the name of the project? [2] Try entering just **http://localhost:8080/contato** instead. Do you still get 404? [3] See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) regarding embedding the content of Tomcat's log file in your question.

Comment: yes it is the name of the project, that's the url that netbeans send me, and if i go to http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2 it shows me the index, i've put in my main response a pastebin with the log, if you see LPW-Aula12 please ignore.

Comment: I copied the `doGet()` of your servlet (except the try block), and all of your **web.xml** to my NetBeans project, and when I enter the URL (http://localhost:8080/WebApplication15/contato in my case) it works fine for me. I  don't see anything wrong with what you are doing. Can you try the following: [1] In NetBeans select your servlet file **contato.java** [2] Right click, and then select **Run File** from the context menu. [3] The **Set Servlet Execution URI** dialog opens. Accept the default value of **/contato** by clicking **OK**. The servlet should open the default browser. What happens?

Comment: Disappointingly nothing happened it actually just get stuck on  Please wait, Servlet Scanning in process, if i let it.
On the other hand, if i cancel, it says, there is no main in contato.

Comment: OK. Try using the `@WebServlet` annotation instead of **web.xml**, as described in [_How to Create Servlet Without web.xml_](https://www.concretepage.com/java-ee/jsp-servlet/how-to-create-servlet-without-web-xml-webservlet-annotation-in-servlet-3): [1] Delete or rename **web.xml**. [2] Insert the line `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/contato2"})` immediately before the line `public class contato...` in your servlet. [3] Rebuild/deploy your web project. [4] In your browser enter http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/contato2  - does that work?

Comment: no it didn't, but that time i got an interesting output i'll link it.
https://pastebin.com/QHrGexXL

Comment: OK. [1] Are you certain that you are not getting any errors when you build your project? [2] Is localhost:8080/WebApplication2 still working, meaning you only have problems with the servlet URL?  [3] Please check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) for any issues around the time you build/deploy? [4] I don't know what the problem is. Can you perhaps create a new web project with a completely different servlet name (using **web.xml** as you did for **contato**) and see if you get a different result? [5] Please update your question with the versions of Java, NetBeans and Tomcat being used.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay, i tried tomcat 7, 8.5, 9.  i didnt tried anything but the java version 8 11, for the linux. and the open jdk, only issue is javacparser didn't parse anything for contato.java, i tried another project, same errors, it just doesn't parse servlets